# How Can I Add Span Tags To This PHP?

Tags: php, html, conditional-statements

I currently have this code: http://pastebin.com/Zdck6Tze wrapped in span tags that is styled a specific way with css. The problem is that the code is dependent on if the user is an affiliate. If they are not, the code does nothing, but the span tags are left there with the styling, and doesn't look good. I would like to add in my span tags into the conditional statement somehow if that is possible? That way, if they are not an affiliate, nothing is output at all.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the span-tags to the echo in the if-statement.

```
<?php
    if (affiliates_user_is_affiliate(get_current_user_id())) {
        echo '<span>' .  do_shortcode(get_field('affiliate_code')) . '</span>';
    }
?>
```